# Pass to url variable with rails render action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such part of controller method:

```
***
else
  @ord_question = @vq
  render :action => :new, :layout => 'admin', :locals => {:order_question_id => @order_question_id}
end
```

all code is here:

http://pastebin.com/nNMF1hag

In my new method, before I forget to enter some field and submit it (validator presence_of), my url is like:

```
...order_answers/new?order_question_id=15
```

But I need to save this get-variable in url order_question_id=15 even after I go into my else method with render :action.

How could I add to render :action url param?

Comment: I think you should reconsider the way you pass `order_question_id` to the form action. I guess nested resources could be used here. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: @MarekLipka it's to long, to rebuild, let's do with this question...

Answer (score 0):

For that you use

```
 redirect_to path
```

in rails.

a standard create in rails 4

```
def create
  @country = Country.new(country_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @country.save
      format.html { redirect_to @country, notice: 'Country was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @country }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @country.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the redirect_to is only done when action was successful. otherwise rails use @vars and files the form by itself.

Comment: maybe then really do this with nesting( ?

Comment: what is done? i see format.html { render action: 'new' } where here i see that i send params with rendering?

Comment: did u get a solution for this?

Comment: @anand: I don't get the question? What do you mean?